# Why is this reference a #VALUE! Error?

Tags: excel

I have written following formula: `=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&BondList&"'!D16")*INDIRECT("'"&BondList&"'!D13"))/D13`, where `bondList` is returning `{"Bond1";"Bond2"}`(both are valid sheet names), and the references have follwing values:

```
Bond1:D13 1000
Bond1:D16 70
Bond2:D13 2000
Bond2:D16 80
```

Even if I would have made a typo in sheet names Excel would have returned '#REF!' but this is apparently an error with data [type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-a-VALUE-error-cec24732-88fc-4b76-945c-32fd4e847573), that eing said I see that the error is raised right after `Indirect` is evalueated and not when evaluating `*`.

I have never seen anything like this. That being said I did an experiment shere I alter the formula to this `=SUM(--ISERROR(INDIRECT("'"&BondList&"'!D16")))` and it returns `2`.

Lastly in order to avoid [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I shoudl mention that I am trying to get a weighted average of values in `D16` to which weights are located at `D13` on each sheet respectively.

Comment: Can you add an helper column (It would make life much easier...)?

Comment: the INDIRECT function is very fragile when it comes to array formulas.  I am guessing it doesn't like that.

Comment: Actually I woudl love to avoid this I have dozens of metrics that I would need it then

Comment: Didn't you add a helper range for `BondList`?  Is that used anywhere else?  If not it might be easier to replace that range with the weighted values

Answer (score 2):

It can be tricky using `INDIRECT` to return arrays of values.

For the weighted average, as you describe, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(INDIRECT("'" & BondList & "'!D16"))*N(INDIRECT("'" & BondList & "'!D13")))/SUMPRODUCT(N(INDIRECT("'" & BondList & "'!D13")))
```

If you create a formula such as:

```
=ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("'" & BondList & "'!D16"))
```

and look at the individual elements of the returned array, either by selecting formula in the formula bar, and hitting `F9`, or by using the `INDEX` function, you will see it evaluates to {FALSE;FALSE}.  So, even though the values appear to be numbers, Excel is not seeing them as such.  The `N` function converts them to values Excel will see as numeric.

Comment: Woah this N function doesn't even make sense.  The evaluate window is literally showing `N({#VALUE!;#VALUE!})` => `{1000;2000}`.  magic I say (+1)

Comment: @chancea  The evaluate window is frequently incorrect.  Examine the results in the manner I described in my post.

Comment: Oh no don't get me wrong that's exactly what I did.  I just find it interesting that the evaluate window shows `N(INDIRECT({"'Sheet2'!D16";"'Sheet3'!D16"}))` => `N({#VALUE!;#VALUE!})` => `N{1000;2000}`.  The N function is basically allowing INDIRECT to use arrays.